# Error: Two main PROGRAMs at (1) and (2)

Tags: fortran

I'm using the Simply Fortran compiler and when I try to compile I get the error:

prog.f95:35.13:
1 Implicit None

prog.f95:53.65:
2 open (unit=1,file='in',status='OLD') ! opens file with parameters

Error: Two main PROGRAMs at (1) and (2)

I have included only the parts of the code in which the errors occur since the whole thing is quite long. This begins at the very beginning of the program.  Let me know if I should include more.

```
Implicit None
Integer :: i,j,iter
real(8) :: Elow,Ehigh,chi,B_NS,Vbrprof,Neprof,taues
real(8) :: Xcyclave,a

character(8) systemdate
character(10) systemtime
character(5) timezone
integer dateandtime(8)

character(8) systemdate2
character(10) systemtime2
character(5) timezone2
integer dateandtime2(8)

character(len=40) ::  infname,outfname,comm
include 'common.f95'

open (unit=1,file='in',status='OLD')    ! opens file with parameters

read (1,1)                              ! comment line
read (1,1) outfname
read (1,*) Elow,Ehigh                   ! lower and higher energy
read (1,*) Eminf,Emind,Emaxf            ! min and max energy for fedd
read (1,*) Rin, Rout                    ! inner and outer radii
read (1,*) profpar(1)                   ! for Ne
read (1,*) profpar(2)                   ! Te in keV
read (1,*) profpar(3)                   ! for absorption+emission
read (1,*) profpar(4)                   ! T_bb for neutron star in keV
read (1,*) profpar(5)                   ! for bulk velocity
read (1,*) profpar(6)                   ! other parameter for model
read (1,*) profpar(10)                  ! magnetic moment in 10^27 CGS
1 format (A10)
close (1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is probably seeing an END xxx statement in the file common.f95.  The file common.f95 is possibly not meant to be used as an INCLUDE file - it may be a program unit in its own right.